# Get information about changed file in Java

Tags: java, file, watchservice, apache-commons-io, file-monitoring

I'm trying to monitor files in java. When a file modification will happen I want to know:

1. Which process did the change.
2. What has changed.

Also, I know that there is a way to change the "last modified date" in a file, so I want to check if someone has changed that field.

I tried "commons.io", "DefaultFileMonitor" and "WatchService", but all the information I could get from them was if a change has occurred and the file that was changed.

Comment: If you wanted to know the exact changes that happened, you'd need to know the contents of the file before the change, and then compare that to the modified file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on a weird OS I know absolutely nothing about, you would need to use some mechanism you implement to track who is changing your file. The OS doesn't keep track of that. It also doesn't track what has changed.

So I don't believe you can do #1 unless you can get every process that MIGHT change the file to track that it did a change.

You could do #2 if you kept copies of the file then do a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**I am pretty sure you cannot do that.** Neither OS nor Java is storing such information. Maybe using some kernel calls.